# Adding/updating 'news' to an app without updating the app

Tags: android, ios, html, css, cordova

I am attempting to create a simple app by using html/css in Cordova. However I am stuck in one area and that is updating the news page content. I don't really know what method I can use to achieve this without having to update the whole app and resubmitting onto the store and I don't really know what I need to google to get the answer so I thought I would ask here and hopefully someone can help me out?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to have some sort of server where you would store your news content and later download it through API to your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can make jQuery `ajax` calls to the web server and fetch news. Update them in news section on successful retrieval. Make these calls when user opts to refresh or after certain time interval.

Something like -

```
$.ajax({            
    url     :   'fetchNewsFrom.php', //some server page to retrieve news from db and return
    type    :   "POST",
    dataType:   "json",
    data    :   {fromTime : $someTimestamp}, //fetch latest news since some time
    success :   function (result){
          console.log(result);  //has fetched results
          //update your news section with fetched news
    }
});
```

You can also do push notifications using [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push). There is something called [topic messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging). You can subscribe the users to topics and push the updated news to subscribed users.